# Add to cart button not working in Magento

Tags: javascript, magento

The add to cart button on my website is not working. Here is an example page: http://www.fluffyflump.co.uk/pot-of-gold-art-print

When click inspect element and console I can see the error: Cannot call method 'submit' of undefined

The setup is Magento 1.7.0.2 and a custom theme which I have used before with no problems.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You have a conflict between Prototype JS and jQuery.

It's a common problem when two JS frameworks are used in the same  website.

Check this to know how to use `noConflict();` and prevent the conflict.
http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

Basically you will need to use `jQuery.noConflict();` between prototype and jQuery.

Comment: Thanks Kalpesh, I understand what you are saying but implementing it sounds tricky. Would I implement it on that function / file only?

Comment: just create one js file, with content `jQuery.noConflict();` and include it between prototypeJS and jQuery.

Comment: So I can a js file, with the only content being jQuery.noConflict(); and upload it via FTP to the JS folder? Not sure if that sounds right?

Comment: yes and also you will need to include that JS file in Magento (head section)

Comment: I created a file called noconflict.js with the contents " jQuery.noConflict(); " and uploaded it to /js and added the following to the head.html page file <script type="text/JavaScript" src="js/noconflict.js"></script> - this hasn't fixed it. What did I do wrong?

Comment: http://www.9magentothemes.com/forums/threads/369-Magento-amp-jQuery-How-to-use-them-together?s=18867487c4ee63ec558b81b47e77407b

Comment: Thanks Kalpesh, going to try these now and ill let you know if it works.